# gwt-maven-plugin : compilation error

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I upgraded my gwt from 2.5 to 2.8 after the upgrade am getting the below error

`gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) @ SeviS4Web [ERROR] Jun 22, 2017 1:16:06 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init> [ERROR] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'com.sevi.web.SEWeb'`

All the modules got loaded Then the below log and the errror

```
Public resources found in... [INFO] Translatable source found in... 
[INFO] Persistent unit cache dir set to: 
C:\Jesline\Project_Linux\target\gwt-unitCache [INFO] Opening cache file:     
C:\Jesline\Project_Linux\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-
f160a61272c5ebe805cd2d3d3256ed3ecf14893f-0000015CD0B5FBB0 [INFO] Looking 
for previously cached Compilation Units in 
C:\Jesline\Project_Linux\target\gwt-unitCache [INFO] Compiling module 
com.citi.sevi.web.SEWeb [INFO] Found 0 cached/archived units. Used 0 / 
5180 units from cache. [INFO] Compiling... [INFO] [ERROR] An internal 
compiler exception occurred [INFO] 
 com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Error constructing Java AST [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.translateException(GwtAstBuilder.java:3944) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.getInternalCompilerException(GwtAstBuilder.java:4351) [INFO] 
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMembers(GwtAstBuilder.java:4043) [INFO] 
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMembers(GwtAstBuilder.java:4039) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.processImpl(GwtAstBuilder.java:3883) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3918) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:129) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:384) [INFO] 
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:1092) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:325) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:548) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:479) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:465) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:222) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50) [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125) 
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodBinding.isDefaultMethod()Z 
[INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMethod(GwtAstBuilder.java:4138)  [INFO] at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMembers(GwtAstBuilder.java:4033) [INFO] ... 22 more [INFO] 
[ERROR] at CustomDateTimeFormat.java(41): public @interface Pattern 
[INFO] org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration [INFO] 
[ERROR] at CustomDateTimeFormat.java(28): public interface CustomDateTimeFormat extends com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.CustomDateTimeFormat 
[INFO] org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration [INFO] Closing cache 
file: C:\Jesline\Project_Linux\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-f160a61272c5ebe805cd2d3d3256ed3ecf14893f-0000015CD0B5FBB0 (0 units written) 
[INFO] Deleting empty file: C:\Jesline\Project_Linux\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-f160a61272c5ebe805cd2d3d3256ed3ecf14893f-0000015CD0B5FBB0 [INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread [INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Comment: This is a classpath conflict issue. You have an incompatible JDT/ECJ in the classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Add this key to registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs

Comment: This is not the actual issue the OP has.